# Programmatically getting Decoration Status of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

this seams to be a simple one - but I couldn't find an answer here or elsewhere:

How do I get the Decoration Status of a JFrame at runtime? I imagine something like this should exist:

```
this.myJFrame.getDecoration();   // returns true or false
```

or

```
this.myJFrame.isDecorated();  // returns true or false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [`JFrame#isUndecorated`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#isUndecorated()), which goes with [`JFrame#setUndecorated`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated(boolean))

Comment: How on earth could I miss that?! I believe I was looking only for the positive term "decorated" and not the negative "undecorated". Sorry for wasting your time! And thank you! Marked as correct.

Comment: Yeah, I'd be looking for get/setDecorated too :P